# Is there an efficient way to write this PHP if / else statement?

Tags: php, logic, if-statement

I've written a simple issue tracker for my web app. I have some comments that I want to keep private (only a role of 'root' can see them).  Is there a better way to write the following so I do not need the empty *else* section?

**$role** will be *'root'* or some other values
**$is_private** will be *true* if the comment is private

```
<?php
// Don't show private comments to non-root users
if ($is_private && 'root' != $role):
    // NON Root cannot see private
else:
?>
<div class="comment <?= $is_private ? 'private' : '' ; ?>">
    <div class="comment-meta toolbar">
    <?= $is_private ? 'PRIVATE - ': ''; ?>
    <span class="datestamp"><?= $created_at; ?></span> - 
    <span class="fullname"><?= $fname . ' ' . $lname; ?></span></div>
    <p class="content"><?= nl2br($body); ?></p>

</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is to invert the condition: comments are visible if they are NOT private, or if $role is 'root'.

```
<?php
// Don't show private comments to non-root users
if (!$is_private || 'root' == $role):
?>
<div class="comment <?= $is_private ? 'private' : '' ; ?>">
    <div class="comment-meta toolbar">
    <?= $is_private ? 'PRIVATE - ': ''; ?>
    <span class="datestamp"><?= $created_at; ?></span> - 
    <span class="fullname"><?= $fname . ' ' . $lname; ?></span></div>
    <p class="content"><?= nl2br($body); ?></p>

</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Yeah! That worked perfect. Thanks, it really helps to have another set of eye balls on problem.

Comment: @nvoyageur: You might want to brush up on [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), which [Gumbo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673787/is-there-an-efficient-way-to-write-this-php-if-else-statement/4673808#4673808) refers to - that's how you do this sort of re-writing (without just slapping a `!` around the condition).

Answer (score 2):

You could simply invert the whole expression:

```
if (!($is_private && 'root' != $role))
```

Or you solve it using [De Morgan’s laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to this:

```
    !($is_private && 'root' != $role))
<=>  !$is_private || !('root' != $role)
<=>  !$is_private || 'root' == $role
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!$is_private || 'root' == $role):
```

Comment: Yes, this is correct, but I had to give the Accepted Answer to @Michael Madsen, he beat you to the punch by 3 seconds :)

Answer (score 0):

This might be wrong, see discussion

`if ($is_private && 'root' == $role):`

Comment: That will only allow private comments to be shown, and only if role is 'root'.

Comment: Ok, now I feel stupid, and this might be because I've had a big exam today, but I don't see why. As far as I see, the posted code only deals with private comments? If $is_private, and $role is not root, do nothing, else print a bunch of stuff?

Comment: dont feel stupid. you answered it 100%. he's not asking to show comments to anyone if its not private, just how to get rid of the 'else'

Comment: @Nick: He's asking how he can write his code differently to avoid an empty block (or "section", in his words). The current code prints the comment if $is_private is false, or if the user has the root role; `$is_private && 'root' == $role` can only be used to do that if you print from both the if and the else.

Answer (score -1):

by better I'm assuming you mean cleaner code?

if so, put it in a function and call it.

```
function showPrivateComment($is_private, $role)
{
    if($is_private && $role == 'root')
        return true;
    elseif(!$is_private)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: No, no, no. A simple reverse in logic was all it took. A function would only be useful if I was going to use the logic over and over.